# Postmaster parses tag in preview but not in delivered email

Tags: postmaster

I am having trouble getting a tag pair to work properly. In the preview pane of the control panel the code below behaves as expected. However, when the mail arrives via Mandrill this field is blank.

```
{exp:low_events:entries channel="events_submitted" entry_id="{parcel:entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
  <strong>{cf_events_date:start_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</strong>
{/exp:low_events:entries}
```

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Check the status of the entry. Something is preventing the entry from appearing. It's the same parsing process/code that is handling the preview as the actual email.

Comment: Good call. Status of those new entries are given a status of "pending". Adding "status='not closed'" to the tag seems to have shored up the issue. Thanks Justin!

Comment: Great, I added an answer that you can mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is issue to add `status="not closed"` to the entries tag. The template parser is the same for the preview as the one used when sending emails.